# Вывод в item RecyclerView данных по нескольким запросам

Tags: android

Есть таблица, в которую будут записывать доходы и расходы с указанием даты.

Хочу выводить расходы в таком виде как на картинке. В `RecyclerView` в одном `item` выводить расходы за текущий день, неделю и месяц, во втором `item` выводить доходы, в третьем `item` - итоговый баланс доходы минус расходы.

Т.е. данные по трем запросам.. Это возможно реализовать или подойти к этому иначе? Хотелось бы услышать мнение как вообще реализовать такое?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, Вас интересует то, можно ли выводить разные item в одном RecyclerView. В этом случае, можете посмотреть что-то в этом плане - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVJpWSalzbo . Но, если Вы не сохраняете историю, то есть ли смысл делать это в RecyclerView ? Если можно просто выводить данные на активити.

Comment: это приложение для учета доходов и расходов,данные будут записываться в таблицу ежедневно. Попробую реализовать вывод на активити во View. Думал наоборот в RecyclerView будет правильнее..

Comment: Я не говорю, что мой вариант правильный, лично я бы так сделал и не более. Просто, в основном, в RecyclerView выводят какой-то список, к примеру - список новостей. Также можно сделать подгрузку данных в этот RecyclerView и т.п. . Поэтому, не вижу смысл в нем в этой ситуации. А если Вам нужен такой же дизайн, как на фото, то можете в лаяуте просто вставить тот же CardView и в нем добавить элементы, которые надо выводить.

Comment: если используется только три "айтема" и их число не изменяется, то использование RecyclerView не имеет никакого смысла. это просто три CardView с собственными разметками и никак не связаны

Comment: Спасибо, попробую без recyclerview